# issue with puppeteer console.log

Tags: puppeteer

i just want to use XPath to get innerText using Puppeteer. This is code

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core';
(async () => {
    // Make the browser visible by default, extend the timeout, and set a default viewport size
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
      userDataDir: 'C:\\ctvbanhang\\browserData',
      defaultViewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
      headless: false, // true = hide screen, false = show screen
      timeout: 60000, // 60 seconds
    });

    // The browser automatically opens a page, so use that
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    await page.goto('https://example.com/');

    var XPath = "//h1/text()";//       //'div.product-briefing > div > div > div > span';
    // //await page.waitForSelector(selector);
    await page.waitForXPath(XPath);
    let result = await page.evaluate(element => {
        console.log(element);                     //log in browser
        console.log(typeof element);               //log in browser
        console.log(JSON.stringify(element));      //log in browser
        return element;
    }, (await page.$x(XPath))[0]);

    console.log(result);                          //log in terminal

    await page.waitFor(100000);

    await browser.close();
  })()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Browser scans complete!');
  })
```

Why the result is not the same?
this is result log in browser
[image]
and in terminal
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, various eval functions can transfer only serializable data (roughly, the data JSON can handle, with some additions). Your code returns a DOM element ([Text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)), which is not serializable (it has methods and circular references). Try to retrieve the data in the browser context and returns only serializable data. For example:

```js
return element.wholeText;
```